# What function does "as" in the Swift syntax have?

Tags: swift

Recently I stumbled upon a syntax I cannot find a reference to: What does **as** mean in the Swift syntax?

Like in:

```
var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch!
```

Unfortunately, it's hard to search for a word like **as**, so I didn't find it in the Swift Programming Language handbook by Apple. Maybe someone can guide me to the right passage?

And why does the element after **as** always have an **!** to denote to unwrap an Optional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`as` keyword](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) is used for casting an object as another type of object. For this to work, the class **must** be convertible to that type.

For example, this works:

```
let myInt: Int = 0.5 as Int // Double is convertible to Int
```

This, however, doesn't:

```
let myStr String = 0.5 as String // Double is not convertible to String
```

You can also perform optional casting (commonly used in `if-let` statements) with the `?` operator:

```
if let myStr: String = myDict.valueForKey("theString") as? String {
    // Successful cast
} else {
    // Unsuccessful cast
}
```

---

In your case, `touches` is (I'm assuming from the `anyObject()` call) an `NSSet`. Because `NSSet.anyObject()` returns an `AnyObject?`, you have to cast the result as a `UITouch` to be able to use it.

In that example, if `anyObject()` returns nil, the app will crash, because you are forcing a cast to `UITouch!` (explicitly unwrapping). A safer way would be something like this:

```
if let touch: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as? UITouch {
  // Continue
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful and illustrating example, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`as` is an operator that cast a value to a different type.

For example:

Suppose you have an `NSSet` instance with some elements that have a type `Car`.
Then if you want to get any object:`Car` from this set, you should call anyObject().

```
var someCar = set.anyObject() //here someCar is Optional with type AnyObject (:AnyObject?), because anyObject() -> AnyObject?
```

Let's imagine the situation when you need to get an object from the set with type `Car`.

```
var realCar: Car = someCar as Car //here realCar is Optional with type Car (:Car?)
```

Than if you exactly know that someCar is not an Optional ( someCar != nil) you can do follow:

```
var realCarAndNotAnOptional = someCar as Car! //here realCarAndNotAnOptional just have a type == Car
```

More info here: [Swift: Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

Answer (score 2):

> A constant or variable of a certain class type may actually refer to
>   an instance of a subclass behind the scenes. Where you believe this is
>   the case, you can try to downcast to the subclass type with the type
>   cast operator (as).

from [Swift Programming Language, Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

> And why does the element after as always have an ! to denote to unwrap an Optional?

It is not. It is trying to downcast to "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals", see [Swift Programming Language, Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)